# How can I disable collapse in jstree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Basically, what I am trying to do is, I want to display the content which falls under the same category in tree structure as a child-parent node instead of folder structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was found on https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1101

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    $.jstree.plugins.noclose = function () {
        this.close_node = $.noop;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#tree').jstree({
    plugins : ["noclose", ... ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: do you know how I can adapt this solution to prevent root node only from collapsing? Because if I use the above answer, all nodes will be prevented from collapsing

Comment: Hi @jo12345678 I don't know the exact solution, you can research on it. :)